# Sort map by value, then by property in the key?

Tags: java, java-6

I've got a `Map<User, Integer>`, where the `Integer` is a weight. Each user has an id. I want to return a `List<User>` where the users are sorted first by weight, but if weight are equal I want them sorted by the user id. I've come up with one aproach, but I think there's something I'm missing as I think it should be simpler.. Can someone help me out? My current approach is below.

Note: I'm working with Java 6.

```
public List<User> sortUsers(Map<User, Integer> userWeightMap) {
  SortedSet<Map.Entry<CustomObject, Integer>> sortedSet = new TreeSet<Map.Entry<CustomObject, Integer>>(new Comparator<Map.Entry<CustomObject, Integer>>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(Map.Entry<CustomObject, Integer> e1, Map.Entry<CustomObject, Integer> e2) {
          if (e1.getValue() == e2.getValue()) {
              // Weights are equal, sort by id instead
              if (e1.getKey().getUser().getId() > e2.getKey().getUser().getId()) {
                  return 1;
              } else {
                  return -1;
              }
          } else {
              return e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue());
          }
      }
  });
  sortedSet.addAll(userWeightMap.entrySet());

  ArrayList<CustomObject> userSortedByWeightThenId = new ArrayList<CustomObject>();
  for (Map.Entry<CustomObject, Integer> bestiltDelstrekningIntegerEntry : sortedSet) {
      userSortedByWeightThenId.add(bestiltDelstrekningIntegerEntry.getKey());
  }
  return userSortedByWeightThenId;
}
```

Comment: If you're *really* stuck with Java 6 as per your tag (which I'd call out more clearly in the question) then something like that comparator is reasonable, although I'd probably structure it slightly differently.

Comment: Thank you. I'm stuck with java 6 so I'll make that clearer in the question.

Comment: Can you change the map structure or are you stuck with User to Integer?

Comment: The input has to be a `Map`, but I could change the type of map.

Comment: cause i would have used map<Integer, List<User>>. the map sort your weight and list sort the user with the same weight.
then cycle through and add them to list

Comment: I would straight up just return the `SortedSet`. That way the caller will have something in the contract which says "this thing is sorted". If they try to add a user to the collection for whatever reason, it will get added at the right place. I can't see any benefit to putting the entire Set into a List.

Comment: I have to keep the signature and return a `List<User>`. I'll try that approach, @Zeromus, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you explained your situation you have to maintain the method signature like this

`public List<User> sortUsers(Map<User, Integer> userWeightMap)`

Then I find your approach is okay. I refactored your code and tried the following way.

```
public static List<User> sortUsers(Map<User, Integer> userMap) {

        Comparator<Map.Entry<User, Integer>> comparator = new Comparator<Map.Entry<User, Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Map.Entry<User, Integer> e1, Map.Entry<User, Integer> e2) {

                if(e1.getValue().equals(e2.getValue())){
                    return e1.getKey().getId() > e2.getKey().getId() ? 1 : -1;
                }

                return e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue());
            }
        };

        List<Map.Entry<User, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<User, Integer>>(userMap.entrySet());

        Collections.sort(list, comparator);

        List<User> sortedList = new LinkedList<>();
        for(Map.Entry<User, Integer> entry : list) {
            sortedList.add(entry.getKey());
        }

        return sortedList;
    }
```

Here I used the `Collections.sort()` util function. As this method taked `List` as argument. I preferred to take the `List` of `Map.Entry` of the `userMap`. Then simply use the comparator to sort the list. `LinkedList` is used to ensure the insertion order thus the sorting.

N.B: Currently I am not able to check the Java SE 6 syntax for this code. But I hope there is no problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your `CustomObject` is good for.

You should not repeatedly add to a SortedSet like TreeSet, because each add can rearrange the order and therefore wastes performance.
Instead you should `sort` the final List in a single run.

E.g. like so:

```
public List<User> sort(final Map<User, Integer> userToWeight) {
    Comparator<User> primaryWeightSecondaryId = new Comparator<User>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(User left, User right) {
            Integer leftWeight = userToWeight.get(left);
            Integer rightWeight = userToWeight.get(right);
            int primary = leftWeight.compareTo(rightWeight);
            if (primary != 0) {
                return primary;
            }
            // secondary
            return Integer.valueOf(left.getId()).compareTo(right.getId());
        }
    };

    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>(userToWeight.keySet());
    Collections.sort(users, primaryWeightSecondaryId);
    return users;
}
```